# How can ReactJS gets notified and update UI on Firebase database updates

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need some technical design guidance on how to do this.

I have a webapp that is build on ReactJS and I have a Firebase Database
I would like to update realtime data from Firebase Database updated to the ReactJS UI (filtered to particular user/account)

I know that we can listen to Firebase Database events from Functions using these guidance:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Can reactJS subscribe to certain events from function to get these triggers ?

I would like real-time information appearing on the ReactJS page. Can someone advise how would this be designed / architectured ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to update realtime data from Firebase Database updated to
> the ReactJS UI

Both the two database services offered by Firebase, i.e. [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), offer the possibility to get realtime updates from the database in your front-end.

- For Firestore, you'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) in the doc the details on how to listen to a Document, a Query or an entire Collection.
- For the Realtime Database you'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) in the doc the details on how to listen to a specific node of the JSON-like data tree.

So, in the Firebase world, setting such real-time listeners is the standard way for having "real-time information appearing on the ReactJS page".

---

> I know that we can listen to Firebase Database events from Functions
> using these guidance:
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

This is about triggering a *background* Cloud Function **in the Google Cloud back-end**, based on some events occurring in the database (e.g. update, deletion or creation). In this framework, there is no out-of-the-box mechanism to be informed, from your front-end, that such a *background* Cloud Function was triggered (based on some changes in the database).